# std::experimental::generator write access violation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, generator, access-violation

I am running this code on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and I am getting really weird access violation error at the place denoted below. If I simplify the expression to something like `int mid = (max - min) / 2;` the code works fine.

```
#include <experimental/generator>

std::experimental::generator<int> range(int min, int max)
{
    int mid = min + (max - min) / 2;  // write access violation
    yield mid;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto x : range(10, 20)) { }
}
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem? I am suspecting that it might be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2337518/std-experimental-generator-write-access-violation

It will be reportedly fixed in Update 2